# Python Machine Learning with Audio (predictive Maintenance)

Tags: python, machine-learning, audio, deep-learning

I am new to machine Learning with python. I would like to create an ML application that makes different assignments through different sounds. I would like to use the microphone to read the sound and classify it.

Are there already existing applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can have a look here:
https://github.com/luuil/tensorflow-audio-classification

It's seems like you can classify audio with this fairly easily. After classifying you can do whatever assignment you want.

But it does seem like you can not identify the sound with your microphone out of the box.